# Blazor EditForm missing Email and Phone?

Tags: blazor-server-side

Is there a validator for Emails and Phone # in EditForm like there is in Form (e.g.) "tel" for phone and "email" for emails.

Even though they test for formatting not existence of phone and email.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
What i did was ; create a public class and link this to the editform.
Using Regex expressions you can create your own validation.

```cs
    public class RegisterAccountModel
        {
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email adres Missing")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Unvalid Email Address")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
    
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Paswoord Missing")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [StringLength(100)] //, ErrorMessage = "Paswoord dient minstens {2} characters te bevatten waaronder minstens één nummer.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [Display(Name = "Paswoord")]
            [RegularExpression("^()(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}$", ErrorMessage = "Min 6 characters and 1 capital letter.")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Paswoord not Matching")]
            [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Paswoord not Matching")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Company Is Empty")]
            public string Bedrijfsnaam { get; set; }
    
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name is empty)]
            public string Naam { get; set; }
    
        }
```

When you want to use this class in your edit form you can do :

```html
    <EditForm Context="NewUser" OnSubmit="FormSubmitted" Model="registerAccountModel">
       <div class="DataValidationRemark">@RegisterRemarks</div>
         <DataAnnotationsValidator />
         <ValidationSummary />
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td><p class="label">Email:</p></td>
          <td><p><InputText @bind-Value="registerAccountModel.Email" /></p></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><p class="label">@lblPassword :</p></td>
           <td><p><input type="password" @bind-value="registerAccountModel.Password" /</p></td> 
       </tr>
    </EditForm>
```

Regarding the submit : This needs to be on your razor page. or code behind file.

```cs
    @code {
    private RegisterAccountModel registerAccountModel = new RegisterAccountModel();

    public void FormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
    {
    
        isValidated = editContext.Validate();
    
        if (isValidated)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RegisterUser());
    
        }
    
    }
```

Regarding the register user : still on the same razor page

```cs
    private async Task RegisterUser()
    {
        //If the form validation is done
        if (isValidated)
        {
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = registerAccountModel.Email, Email = registerAccountModel.Email, EmailConfirmed = false }, registerAccountModel.Password);
    
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //DO STUFF
            }
         }
        }
      }
```

Let me know if it worked for you, or if you got stuck.

Regards,

Mathias